# Algorithms for 3-way partitioning

Tags: algorithm, partitioning, quicksort

The *3-way partitioning* splits an array into 3 sub-arrays: elements < pivot, elements == pivot, elements > pivot.

We can use the well-known solution for E. Dijkstra's "Dutch Flag Problem" to do that but [Bentley and McIlroy](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort-3-way) suggest another [way](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/) (see section #22, "*Fast three-way partitioning*")

Unfortunately I do not understand *how* their algorithm is better (faster). Could anybody explain it slowly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses fewer swaps on average, at least while there are not too few different elements in the array.

The "Dutch Flag" algorithm uses one swap per element not equal to the pivot, so that's

```
n - multiplicity(pivot)
```

swaps.

The alternative, which swaps the elements equal to the pivot to the ends of the array first, swaps each element equal to the pivot twice (once to one end, and finally to the middle), and swaps pairs `a[i], a[j]` with `i < j` and `a[j] < pivot < a[i]`, that's

```
2*multiplicity(pivot) + count(bad_pairs)
```

swaps. The number of bad pairs cannot be more than `(n - multiplicity(pivot))/2` and is usually (random array) smaller, off the top of my head, I'd expect something like `(n-multiplicity(pivot))/4` or less on average. So if `multiplicity(pivot) < n/5`, the alternative is guaranteed to use fewer swaps, and if my estimate is right, it will on average use fewer swaps if `multiplicity(pivot) < 3*n/11`.

So if you know a priori that there are only very few (<= 5 or so) distinct elements in the array, I think "Dutch Flag" will be superior, but in general, the alternative will use fewer swaps until the parts to be sorted have become rather small.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. BTW, is it correct that the 3-way partitioning makes quicksort stable ?

Comment: 3-way partitioning doesn't automatically make it stable, I don't think it's possible without much complication. I'm not even sure one can implement a stable quicksort, 2-way or 3-way partitioning.

Comment: Quicksort for arrays based on 3-way partition is not stable. But Quicksort for linked lists based on 3-way partition can be stable